# Mac Emulator Screen Error. Screen and Touch out of Sync

Tags: macos, osx-lion, emulation

I have the upgraded mountain Lion version of Macbook pro with Retina Display.

When I launch the Android Emulator from Eclipse, the emulator is not normal. Take a look at the picture. The screen does not take up the entire screen. The oddest thing is though, the touch takes up the entire screen. So in order to press the back button, I have to press the bottom left most space in the window, and not where the back button is displayed. How do you extend the screen so that it takes over the entire window and how to do sync the screen and touch?

I have HP Desktop also and this is not a problem there. So I am wondering that this may be a Mac problem

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I can't believe I have to resort to using WINDOWS to emulate Android.

Comment: can anyone solve this issue? PLEASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed long time ago and it is no longer valid.